# how to click on a JS button

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, web-scraping, robobrowser

i'm trying to submit a form using `robobrower` by clicking button named `Renew` which renews all the books which i've checked mark in the check  box, and now all i've go to do is to click on the Renew button,I've tried to submit it by doing `browser.submit_form(box)`. but i'm not sure if it is doing the work or not, because i've heard that `Robobrowser` doesn't support `JS`.. here is my code.

```
box = browser.get_form(action='./selectedBooks')  
box.fields['selectedforRenewal'].value = ['values']  
browser.submit_form(box, submit='Renew')
```

and here is the sourcecode of the button.

```
<td align="middle" valign="center" height="0*">

                                <a class="briefListHREFFoot" href="javascript:showpopupFrame('./renew');"><b>Renew</b></a>

                            </td>
```

Comment: and i'm trying to avoid selenium for this project.

Comment: i figured it out by going to the network tab in the inspect element and then observing what request is being sent when i click the button. then i request at the same url (url which is being generated when i cluck the button in the network tab)